# Issue with Dynamic Titles in Angular 2+ when switching tabs

Tags: angular

I have implemented dynamic titles in angular with no issues.

The only problem is when I change tab, and return back to the website the title is returned to the original.

It works fine, I have the following code on the app.component, but not persistent when switching tabs (safari & chrome mac)

```
import { Title, Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';

    constructor(
        public title: Title
    ){
      this.title.setTitle('custom title');
    }
```

I expected the title to persist when I go elsewhere and return to the tab.

**EDIT:**

OK I userstand now that it puts the title I defined on index.html, meta section:

```
<title>My title</title>
```

However if I don't set the title here instead of default title I get empt name when switching tabs (only URI), I believe its also not good for SEO.. Suggestions?

Comment: Any reason why the title's string is not closed? (Or is it a typo?)

Comment: @Edric ohh yeah, it is more complex on my app, just wanted to simplify it. EDITED

Comment: @ace did you manage to solve this issue? If yes could you please help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean browser tabs or something like a tabs-navigation?

I guess the problem is, that the component might get created even you don't see it. Like in Angular Material Tabs navigation the next not yet visible tab component is already created and therefore the title would get set.

Comment: I mean the browser tabs.
Thanks, so in that case, I will take a look at the whole code and see if I can find what is updating the title on browser tab return

Comment: Looking for "setTitle" there is no other reference anywhere. Do you have any suggestion for my search.

Comment: OK I userstand now that it puts the title I defined on index.html, meta section:
<title>My title</title>

However if I don't set the title here instead of default title I get empt name when witching tabs (ony URI), I believe its also not good for SEO.. Suggestions?